# Get correct output from UTF-8 stored in VarChar using Entity Framework or Linq2SQL?

Tags: linq-to-sql, entity-framework, utf-8

Borland StarTeam seems to store its data as UTF-8 encoded data in VarChar fields. I have an ASP.NET MVC site that returns some custom HTML reports using the StarTeam database, and I would like to find a better solution for getting the correct data, for a rewrite with MVC2.

I tried a few things with `Encoding` GetBytes and GetString, but I couldn't get it to work (we use mostly Delphi at work); then I figured out [a T-SQL function to return a NVarChar from UTF-8 stored in a VarChar](http://www.jasontpenny.com/blog/2009/07/31/sql-function-to-get-nvarchar-from-utf-8-stored-in-varchar/), and created new SQL views which return the data as NVarChar, but it's slow.

The actual problem appears like this: `â€œdescriptionâ€` instead of `“description”`,  in both SSMS and in a webpage when using Linq2SQL

Is there a way to get the proper data out of these fields using Entity Framework or Linq2SQL?

Comment: The data is likely being stored into `VARCHAR` as if it were code page 1252. So it is likely best to try `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes())`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, once you get the data out, you could always try this:

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(item.Description))
```

assuming the field is encoded in the system ANSI page. You might have to create the right encoding with `Encoding.GetEncoding()` if for some reason it isn't (looked up from DB type, for example).

Comment: I had tried similar things that I had found in searching, but I don't think I had seen Encoding.Default before.  Thanks